# Referencing entities from other jars in EAR

Tags: java, jpa, ear, entities

I'm trying to create a layered web proyect with an EAR. I divided the Entities from the DataAccess in order to only allow DataAccess to be called by BusinessLogic.

I'm actually getting this exception:

> Object: co.edu.icesi.i2trading.entities.Statetype@21397ba0 is not a known entity type.

And I found here that I need to create a persistence.xml in the EAR, but I can't really understand how.

[Sharing a persistence unit across components in a .ear file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073635/sharing-a-persistence-unit-across-components-in-a-ear-file)

I tried placing the XML file in the Configuration Files:

[image][image]

And referencing the jar with `<jar-files>` in the persistence.xml;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="I2TradingDataAccessPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/I2DataSource</jta-data-source>
                <jar-file>../I2TradingEntities.jar</jar-file>
                <jar-file>../../I2TradingEntities.jar</jar-file>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="None"/>
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/> -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

With no success. Any idea why? I'm very new to Web Developing and this is getting to my nerves.

I'm also getting this WARNING in the persistence.xml's DESIGN tab:

[image]

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016269/entity-unknown-in-ear-with-persistence-unit-in-another-jar/40030861#40030861) question and its answer; it is basically the same question.

Comment: Hello. I'm working with Netbeans and I just don't understand when they show the folder structure. My folder structure is completely different. Could you please tell me where to place the persistence.xml?

Comment: I don't use Netbeans either and I cannot tell you how it is organizing projects; but I see a folder `dist` containing `I2Trading.ear`. If you expand the ear you can see the directory structure; if you can show me that I could try to tell you where you have to put the persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the instruction `jar-file` interprets any path from the file that holds the `persistence.xml`... So, your configuration specifies that the Entities JAR are siblings of your EAR file.

The best (and easy) solution for your problem is to put the given `persistence.xml`at the META-INF folder of your `I2TradingEntities.jar` and remove the `<jar-file>` instructions from it ... This will instruct the Application Server to create a `PersistenceContext` called "I2TradingDataAccessPU" and to detect any @Entity Class contained in that JAR.